# Pulpino ModelSim issue vsim_auto_compile.so 32bit Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, 32-bit, modelsim, riscv

Hi I have installed Modelsim 32bit version on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have also installed relevant 32bit libs and It works fine. (simulation works fine for other projects)

However I'm getting this issue when I try to run helloworld at pulpino.

```
make helloworld // 100% fine
make vcompile // 100% fine
make helloworld.vsim // this gives following issue. in vsim

** Fatal: ** Error: (vsim-3828) Could not link 
### 'vsim_auto_compile.so': cmd = '/home/ashan/intelFPGA_pro/17.0/modelsim_ase/gcc-4.7.4-linux/bin/gcc -shared -fPIC -m32 -B/usr/lib32 
-o "/tmp/ashan@e420_dpi_8127/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/vsim_auto_compile.so" /home/ashan/git/pulp/pulpino/vsim/work/_dpi/auto_compile@/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/*.o '
```

I think Issue is there in `-o "/tmp/ashan@e420_dpi_8127/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/vsim_auto_compile.so"` since there's no such a file.

can someone please help to overcome this issue.

[UPDATE]
This is the output log of vsim

```
Reading pref.tcl

# 10.5c

# source tcl_files/run.tcl
# vsim -quiet tb -L pulpino_lib -L axi_node_lib -L apb_node_lib -L axi_mem_if_DP_lib -L axi_spi_slave_lib -L axi_spi_master_lib -L apb_uart_sv_lib -L apb_gpio_lib -L apb_event_unit_lib -L apb_spi_master_lib -L fpu_lib -L apb_pulpino_lib -L apb_fll_if_lib -L core2axi_lib -L apb_timer_lib -L axi2apb_lib -L apb_i2c_lib -L zero_riscy_lib -L axi_slice_dc_lib -L riscv_lib -L apb_uart_lib -L axi_slice_lib -L adv_dbg_if_lib -L apb2per_lib "+nowarnTRAN" "+nowarnTSCALE" "+nowarnTFMPC" "+MEMLOAD=PRELOAD" -t ps -voptargs="+acc -suppress 2103" -GTEST="" -gRISCY_RV32F=0 -gZERO_RV32E=0 -gZERO_RV32M=0 -gUSE_ZERO_RISCY=0 
# Start time: 15:23:08 on Aug 30,2017
# ** Warning: (vsim-8311) System Verilog assertions are supported only in Questasim.
# ** Fatal: ** Error: (vsim-3828) Could not link 'vsim_auto_compile.so': cmd = '/home/ashan/intelFPGA_pro/17.0/modelsim_ase/gcc-4.7.4-linux/bin/gcc -shared -fPIC -m32 -B/usr/lib32 -o "/tmp/ashan@e420_dpi_24219/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/vsim_auto_compile.so" /home/ashan/git/pulp/pulpino/vsim/work/_dpi/auto_compile@/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/*.o   '
# (vsim-50) A call to system(/home/ashan/intelFPGA_pro/17.0/modelsim_ase/gcc-4.7.4-linux/bin/gcc -shared -fPIC -m32 -B/usr/lib32 -o "/tmp/ashan@e420_dpi_24219/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/vsim_auto_compile.so" /home/ashan/git/pulp/pulpino/vsim/work/_dpi/auto_compile@/linuxpe_gcc-4.7.4/*.o    >'/tmp/questatmp.WVLMae' 2>&1) returned error code '1'.
# The logfile contains the following messages:
# /home/ashan/intelFPGA_pro/17.0/modelsim_ase/gcc-4.7.4-linux/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: /usr/lib32/crti.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2b) in section `.init'
# /home/ashan/intelFPGA_pro/17.0/modelsim_ase/gcc-4.7.4-linux/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: final link failed: Bad value
# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# 
# No such file or directory. (errno = ENOENT)
# 
# 
# FATAL ERROR while loading design
# Error loading design
# End time: 15:23:09 on Aug 30,2017, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 1, Warnings: 1
```

Main issue is this

```
# The logfile contains the following messages:
    # /home/ashan/intelFPGA_pro/17.0/modelsim_ase/gcc-4.7.4-linux/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: /usr/lib32/crti.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2b) in section `.init'
```

here ld(linker) has it's `SEARCH_DIR` is pointing to `/usr/lib32/`

and it seems there is a compatibility issue. did anyone overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fixed the issue by adding `-dpicpppath`

more details in  [Pulpino Issue track](https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulpino/issues/110#issuecomment-326100024)